# Which kind of VS project to use for WCF-Service hosted on internal Server

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services, wcf-client

I need urgent help and have many questions. I will start by asking what kind of Ms-Vs project should i use (Wcf-Application or Wcf-library) to create a wcf-service, which will be hosted on a local server in my company and will be consumed by a windows phone 7 application.

Hope to find an answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to host your service on localhost using web browser or local IIS server this WCF application is appropriate.
If you want to host your application on console host or window service then WCF library is appropriate.

Comment: thanx 4 ur answer i found it out